# How I'm import type bit(1) from csv into mysql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need help, i'm tried import data from *.csv into my table mysql with MySql Workbench 8.0 table Data Import Wizard

Table name - Device, Namefield - power, Type field - bit(1)

In my *.csv file, I'm write b'1' for field  power, but MySql Workbench 8.0 Wizard print Error - Row import failed with error: ("Data too long for column 'power' at row 1", 1406)

How I write in my *.csv for this type bit(1) field ?

Comment: To long to explain, see this tutorial try something then people can help you for the rest https://medium.com/@AviGoom/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-mysql-database-ef8860878a68

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem myself. If someone comes across a similar problem, then the following helped me:

1. In the csv file, the type b'1' was written with other quotes `, namely b 1`
2. In addition to this, other fields were present in the table and I drew attention to the int (11) field in which I tried to write a number greater than the maximum value
3. Data type int mysql swore if passed it as a number, passed it as a string in straight quotes '' and the data dragged on with a bang.

Comment: I have tried all types of values to attempt importing into an existing table with a bit type and I always get "Date too long" error.  Any chance you can share exactly what your bit `value` looks like in your csv?  I've tried: true, 1, b'1', b\`1\`, TRUE, 0.  None seems to work.